# Drag List to display messages sent time in tchat app Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

Here is what i want to achieve in my message application :

[image: usual ListView] [image: ListView after the drag gesture]

You will notice that this is the layout of the Instagram message page but it's the same on the iMessage native IOS app if i am not mistaken, i would simply like to know how to get this `drag` feature done in Flutter.